# How to set the window's default position?

Tags: c++, windows, position

I'm using Dev C++. After I created a windows application, it generated some code which creates a window. I understand the code broadly. I've found the code to set the size, title, and background color but how do I set up the default position of the new window? I want to start it at the center of the screen.

Comment: Well, in MS VS there is something called "StartPosition" and has a value "CenterScreen", are you sure there is no such thing in Dev C++?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: That exists only for Windows Forms applications that target the .NET Framework. It does not exist in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have CreateWindow function, its definition is as follows:

```
HWND WINAPI CreateWindow(
  __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpClassName,
  __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpWindowName,
  __in      DWORD dwStyle,
  __in      int x,
  __in      int y,
  __in      int nWidth,
  __in      int nHeight,
  __in_opt  HWND hWndParent,
  __in_opt  HMENU hMenu,
  __in_opt  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  __in_opt  LPVOID lpParam
);
```

The `x` and `y` parameters specify the location of the newly-created window. These are the ones you need to set.